# Colors for Regions

Tags: regions

I would like to make different components of my 3D regions show in different colors (colours).
Here are some dimensions for a bolt, washer and plate. I can make the individual components in different colors but when I assemble them (the last graphic) they are all in the same default color.

```
Len = 150/1000;  (*length of plate  *)
ht = 15/1000; (* height *)
wd = 80/1000; (* width *)
rh = 1/2 11/1000; (* hole radius *)
rb = 1/2 10/1000;(* bolt shaft radius *)
rwi = 1/2 (105/10)/1000; (* washer inner radius *)
rwo = 1/2 21/1000; (* washer outside radius *)
hw = 2/1000; (* washer thickness *)
rhd = 1/2 17/1000;(* head radius *)
Lh = (718/100)/1000;(* head length *)

reg1 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  Cuboid[{-Len/2, -wd/2, 0}, {Len/2, wd/2, ht}], 
  MeshCellStyle -> Orange];(* plate *)
reg2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, -ht}, {0, 0, 2 ht}}, rh]];  (* hole*)
reg3 = RegionDifference[reg1, reg2, MeshCellStyle -> {Darker[Orange]}]
reg4 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, ht + hw}}, rb]]; (* bolt shank *)
reg5 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, ht + hw}, {0, 0, ht + hw + Lh}}, 
   rhd]];  (* bolt head *)
reg6 = RegionUnion[reg4, reg5, MeshCellStyle -> {Darker[Green]}]
reg7 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, ht}, {0, 0, ht + hw}}, rwo]]; (* washer *)
reg8 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, ht}, {0, 0, ht + hw}}, rwi]]; (* washer hole*)
reg9 = RegionDifference[reg7, reg8, MeshCellStyle -> {Darker[Yellow]}]
reg = RegionUnion[reg3, reg6, reg9]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I make each component (bolt, washer and plate) have different colors? Thanks

**Edit**

Chip Hurst makes the good suggestion that if it is just for display then `Show` can be used

```
Show[reg3, reg6, reg9]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is actually very useful. If I turn the plate over I can examine the quality of the clearance between the bolt and the hole.

Comment: If it’s just for display you can use `Show` instead of `RegionUnion`. Also FYI if you use `PlotTheme -> “Minimal”` the edges and points will be hidden.

Comment: @ChipHurst I am putting the regions together to make a mesh. However, your suggestion of using `Show` is a good one if I just wish to examine the assembly. Also, thanks for the `PlotTheme` idea.

Comment: For my own clarification: did you position these by hand then? Or use a Mathematica function to “fit” them together by just not allowing the Regions to overlap? This is awesome seeing some CAD type work in an unmodified mma environment!! Very pretty :D

Comment: @CATrevillian It turns out to be very straightforward. All the code is given above. For this case I actually gave the dimensions for each component from the same datum. They then fit together when you apply `RegionUnion`. However, I could have built them using a different datum for each component. Then in order to assemble them you would have to apply translations and rotations so that they all  come together properly. With the color added this makes for good CAD.

Comment: This is quite impressive, then! (not that it wasn't before, but hey!) Clarification ( not another question, ;D ): By datum, you refer to your initial definitions? This, to me, is truly Shakespeare's defined use of awesome, when I say, "This is AWESOME!!!" I want to recommend, even though I hardly even lurk there (for now, anyway!), that you should post this on Community, they would eat this up! Although packaging it up with a UI would be really time-consuming, but fun!!!

Comment: @CATrevillian  By datum I mean that I thought about a global coordinate system into which I could place the components. I then defined each component using that global coordinate system.  Thus when I put them together they all fitted.  Not that special really. The nice thing about this approach is that I can make a mesh for the region and then solve problems using the finite element method.

Comment: Many thanks for this clarification! I was reading it as units, but not quite. Fancy units. Very nice :) (I bet you could use FEM to fit them having been defined with different unit ratios/coordinate systems, though! I’m sure you have already thought of this though! :) ) thanks again for the great work here. Last abuse of the comment system, I swear! Hah!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach is to see where each face in the union came from and assign the colors from there.

```
rmfs = RegionMember /@ {reg3, reg6, reg9};

color[{__, True}] = Darker[Yellow];
color[{_, True, _}] = Darker[Green];
color[_] = Darker[Orange];

centroids = PropertyValue[{reg, 2}, MeshCellCentroid];

facecolors = color /@ Transpose[Through[rmfs[centroids]]];

styles = {2, #[[All, 1]]} -> #[[1, 2]] & /@ 
  GatherBy[Transpose[{Range[MeshCellCount[reg, 2]], facecolors}], Last];

BoundaryMeshRegion[reg, MeshCellStyle -> styles]
```

[image]